# Eloquent Api Resource: show one column from pivot table

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a vehicle database with a many to many relation with my variant and country table. I only want to show the title that's in my pivot (countries_variants) table. But when I set the relation in my api resource file, it shows all the columns from variants, countries_variants and countries table. Is there a way to only get the title from the pivot table?

Here is my Variant Model:

```
public function countries(): BelongsToMany
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'countries_variants')->withPivot('title');
}
```

VariantResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
{
  return [
      'title' => $this->countries->first->title,
  ];
}
```

VariantController.php

```
public function index()
{
   return new VariantCollection(Variant::paginate(50));
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
{
 "data": [
    {
      "title": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Nederland",
        "country_code": "NL",
        "language_code": "NL_nl",
        "pivot": {
          "variant_id": 1,
          "country_id": 1,
          "title": "3/5 deurs"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I just want to show `"title": "3/5 deurs"` and not the other data.
I thought that if I set withPivot('title') in my model, it will only show that title and not the foreign keys (variant_id and country_id). Apparently thought wrong..

I tried adding this as well:

```
'variant_title' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('countries_variants', function () {
  return $this->pivot->title;
}),
```

But the data then returns empty.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I finally figured it out. I looked through the official laravel docs again and I found [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

So I changed my CountryVariant model class to extend Pivot instead of Model.

Like so:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CountryVariant extends Pivot {
    public function variant(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class);
    }
}
```

Now in my VariantResource.php I added this:

```
public function toArray($request): array
{
   $items = [];

   foreach ($this->countries()->get() as $country) {
       $items[$country->language_code] = $country->pivot->only('title');
   }

   return $items;
}
```

I also changed the pivot table names to be singular like: `country_variant` (I had it plural).

Apparently the problem was that in my model it was looking for a primary key which I didn't have in my pivot table. I only had foreign keys and an additional column: 'title'. It took one of my foreign keys and used it as a primary one. So when I extended with `extends pivot` it would ignore the primary key and I could collect my alternate column 'title' by using `country->pivot->only('title')` in my resource file.

I hope this helps some one else.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```php
$this->countries->first->title
```

To

```php
$this->countries->first->title->pivot->title
```

---

When you do `withPivot('title')` you are telling Eloquent to also get `title` column, if you do not do that, you will only get the `keys` (`variant_id` and `country_id` in your case).

More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).

Comment: Hi thanks for you response. However this isn't working either. When I do as you said, I get `Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object`. I saw that the query was selecting the title as `countries_variants.title as pivot_title` so I tried setting it as ` $this->countries->first->pivot_title ` which returned null values.

Comment: can you try doing `dd($this->contries->first)` so we can see what that object has ? But your solution is in this line.

Comment: It does show a collection of the data from my three tables, countries, variants and countries_variants. similar like the output I showed in my post. It shows that the title I wanted is called pivot_title but I don't understand why `$this->countries->first->pivot_title` returns null values

Comment: Sorry for not being of help. I think it is called `pivot_title` because of how the accessors works, `pivot->title` should work, but I am not sure why not... I did not need to get things from pivot tables like you do, that's why I am not 100% sure. I will think something else and comment again.

Comment: At least you try to help and therefore I'm already grateful ;)

Comment: After looking at some documentation and other SO posts, your fix is what I said `->pivot->title` but I do not know why `title` is not an object but you posted that it returns data. So the problem is somewhere else... What I am not sure is what does `first` do ? I mean, I've always used `first()` but no `first` as a property but as a method. Try doing `$this->countries->first()->title->pivot->title`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It keeps saying trying to get pivot from non object. But to make it easier for myself I changed the column 'title' from countries to something else because I had the column title in two tables. So now when I use `'title' => $this->countries->first->title` I do get a json object but the value is still null. So I guess for some reason it is not getting the records with the values of the title column from the database.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, but I cannot figure it out with the information you shared, you need to show more. You can try one more thing, when you call `Variant::paginate(50)` try this (please, keep in mind to use correct relations) `Variant::with('countries')->paginate(50)`.

Comment: That didn't work either. It's weird. But at least I'm a little bit closer to where the problem lies. I'll have a look at it again tomorrow with some fresh eyes. Maybe I'm able to see the problem then.